# When FlatMap will listen to multiple sources concurrently?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

What are the situations which cause `Flux::flatMap` to listen to multiple sources (0...infinity) concurrently?

---

I found out, while experimenting, that when the upstream send signals to `flatMap` in thread `thread-upstream-1` and there are `N` inner streams which flatMap will listen to and each of them send signals in *different* thread: `thread-inner-stream-i` for `1<=i<=N`, than for every `1<=i<=N` if `thread-upstream-1 != thread-inner-stream-i`, `flatMap` will listen **concurrently** to all the inner streams.

I think that it's not exactly true and I missed some other scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flatMap` doesn't do any parallel work, as in: it doesn't change threads. The simplest example is

```
Flux.range(1, 5).hide()
    .flatMap(v -> Flux.range(10 * v, 2))
    .log()
    .blockLast(); //for test purpose
```

This prints:

```
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - request(unbounded)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(10)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(11)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(20)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(21)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(30)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(31)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(40)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(41)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(50)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(51)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onComplete()
```

As you can see, only produces in `main`. If you add a `publishOn` after the initial range, `flatMap` produces everything in the same single thread publishOn will switch to.

What `flatMap` does however is **subscribe** to multiple inner `Publisher`, up to the `concurrency` parameter with a default of `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE` (256).

That means that if you set it to `3`, `flatMap` will map 3 source elements to their inner `Publisher` and subscribe to these publishers, but will wait for at least one to complete before it starts mapping more source elements.

If the inner `Publisher` use `publishOn` or `subscribeOn`, then `flatMap` will naturally let their events occur in the then-defined threads:

```
Flux.range(1, 5).hide()
    .flatMap(v -> Flux.range(v * 10, 2)
                      .publishOn(Schedulers.newParallel("foo", 3)))
    .flatMap(v -> Flux.range(10 * v, 2))
    .log()
    .blockLast(); //for test purpose
```

Which prints:

```
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
[main] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - request(unbounded)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(10)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(11)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(20)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(21)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(30)
[foo-1] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(31)
[foo-4] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(50)
[foo-4] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(51)
[foo-4] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(40)
[foo-4] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onNext(41)
[foo-4] INFO  reactor.Flux.FlatMap.1 - onComplete()
```